# Spring LdapTemplate search by Object attribute

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I would like to find only a single element inside my LDAP by matching an attribute called "Id" that is inside the object.

the LDAP schema is as following

```
> dc=myCompany,dc=com
>    ou=apiRoles     
>       cn=RoleAdmin
>            objectClass : apiRole
>            RoleCode    : 1
>            user (list of them with values)
```

right now i was able to do this query which brings me all the apiRole classes,

```
List<LdapRole> ldapRoles = ( List<LdapRole>)ldapTemplate.search("ou=apiRoles", "(objectClass=apiRole)", new LdapRole());
```

i am kida new to this so from what i understand i look at the base of the tree that is the "ou=apiRoles" and then filter by the object class

now how do i change this to fit what i want... which is to look by the value of the RoleCode.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to query it if you replace `"(objectClass=apiRole)"` with `"(RoleCode=1)"`.

Or you could build a filter. If you're using Spring LDAP 1.3.2:

```
AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
filter.and(new EqualsFilter('RoleCode', '1'));
```

Then you would replace `"(objectClass=apiRole)"` with `filter.encode()`